# Making a number squared and minimum- how is this possble?

Tags: number-theory

Suppose that there are unequal natural numbers $a,b,c,p$,

These numbers are defined to be related by

$$a^2 = \frac{-bp^2+(bc)^2}{p^2}$$

1) what would be the requirements for these numbers($b,c,p$) to satisfy aforementioend relations?

2) How would we be able to minimize the value of $a$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $a^2 = ( \frac{bc}{p} ) ^2 - b$. Taking $p = bx$ and $c = xy$ we get $a^2 = y^2 - b$. Clearly any value can be given to $a$. If, for example, $b = 8$, $c = 2 \cdot 3$ and $p = 2 \cdot 8$ then $a = 1$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for pointing that out. Very careless of me. Should be good now...